# What is meaning of the rightmost numbers in the `/var/log/kern.log`?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, syslog

When using `dmesg` or `cat /var/log/kern.log` commands to dump the kernel log, we can see something like this:

```
[   22.949049] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
```

So, what dose the `22.949049` mean?

Comment: Just off the cuff, I would guess that's the system run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /var/log/kern.log is for logging kernel messages. Sometimes embedded devices only have timer circuits and no clock. So instead of displaying a clock time, the kernel logs it's system uptime (I assume in seconds.)

Answer (score 1):

Syslog is a standard logging facility. It collects messages of various programs and services including the kernel, and stores them, depending on setup, in a bunch of log files typically under /var/log. In some datacenter setups there are hundreds of devices each with its own log; syslog comes here handy too. One just sets up a dedicated syslog server which collects all the individual device logs over the network. Syslog can also save logs to databases, and other stuff.

The dmesg command is used to write the kernel messages in Linux and other Unix-like operating systems to standard output (which by default is the display screen)

According to my /etc/syslog.conf, default /var/log/kern.log captures only the kernel's messages of any loglevel; i.e. the output of dmesg.

/var/log/messages instead aims at storing valuable, non-debug and non-critical messages. This log should be considered the "general system activity" log.

/var/log/syslog in turn logs everything, except auth related messages.

Other insteresting standard logs managed by syslog are /var/log/auth.log, /var/log/mail.log.

Regarding your question: if you need solely kernel messages log, use the kern.log or call dmesg.

22.949049 is time ..for change that format use following link

http://linuxaria.com/article/how-to-make-dmesg-timestamp-human-readable